# Problemas com uib-tooltip-html angularJS

Tags: angularjs, tooltip

estou com umm problema na hora de retornar um valor utilizando o angular-ui-bootstrap.
Tenho uma função para retornar o resultado de cada tooltip dinamicamente em uma tabela o problema é que sempre que retorno o $sce.trustAshtml de uma função ele simplismente não funciona.

```html
<head lang="en">
    
    <title>uib-tooltip-html test</title>
    <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.1/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.3.js"></script>

    <script>
        var app = angular.module("test", ['ui.bootstrap']).config(function($sceProvider) {
            $sceProvider.enabled(false);
        });

        app.controller("testController", function($scope, $http, $interval, $sce) {
          $scope.text = $sce.trustAsHtml('<div>Some text</div>');          
          $scope.text1 = function teste(){
           var text = $sce.trustAsHtml('<div>Some text</div>');
           return text;
          };
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>

<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="testController">

    <p style="margin-top: 5em;" uib-tooltip-html="text" >
        A Thing With an HTML Tooltip
    </p>

    <p style="margin-top: 5em;" uib-tooltip-html="text1" >
        A Thing With an HTML Tooltip
    </p>
    
    <p style="margin-top: 5em;" uib-tooltip="text1" >
        A Thing With a Tooltip without html
    </p>

</div>
```

Comment: Já tentou fazer isso: `uib-tooltip-html="text1()"` ?

Comment: Estou utilizando mais recebo o erro ` "Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!`

Comment: Eu editei esse exemplo que tu postou e funcionou, será que não está esquecendo de nada?

Comment: O problema foi meu config que como era em documentos separados ele não setava o $sceProvider, por isso que funcionou no jsFiddle e no sistema não funcionava

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema era o .config que não estava funcionando e setando o $sce.provider e foi alterado

de

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module("taskList")
    .config(function ($sceProvider) {
        $sceProvider.enabled(false);
    });
});
```

Para

```
'use strict';

angular
.module("taskList")
.config(TaskListConfig);

TaskListConfig.$inject = ["$sceProvider"];

function TaskListConfig($sceProvider)
{
    $sceProvider.enabled(false);
};
```